# Laravel login not working in edge and internet explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, laravel-5, authentication, microsoft-edge

Login with Laravel 5 is not working with Edge and Internet Explorer, while working perfectly fine in other browsers.

We suspect it has something to do with the sessions not being properly stored but to be honest we have no idea what causes this problem.

When we login in with proper details, the login logic is fired and completed properly, but after that its just redirected back to the login page, so is likely that the middleware thinks that the user is not logged in and returns them to the login page, that is why we think is has something to do with the sessions.

This is our login script:

```
    $rules = array('email' => 'required|email|min:3|max:60',
                   'password' => 'required|min:6|max:20');

    $attributeNames = array(
       'email' => strtolower(Lang::get('auth.email')),
       'password' => strtolower(Lang::get('auth.password')),     
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    $validator->setAttributeNames($attributeNames);

    if ($validator->fails()){ return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator); die(); } 

    //Make an login attempt
    $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
        'role' => 'admin'
    ), false);

    if(!$auth){ 

        $auth2 = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'role' => 'user'
        ), false);

        if(!$auth2){ 

            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(Lang::get('auth.errorText'))->withInput(Input::all());
            die();
        }

    }

    //If user is not activated
    if(Auth::User()->activated != 'OK'){

        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(Lang::get('auth.notActivated'));
        die();
    }

    if(Auth::User()->sms_verificatie == '1') {

        $user = Auth::User();
        $user->sms_ok = 0;
        $user->save();

        $sms_codes_verwijderen = UsersSMSLogin::where('id_cms_users','=',Auth::User()->id)->delete();

        return Redirect::route('sms-verificatie');
        die();

    }

    Session::forget('dashboard_werkgever');

    return Redirect::route('dashboard');
```

Comment: What is your error\issue? It will be useful to better understand what exactly is happening.

Comment: Thats the funny part, the browser just seems to reload the login page while we made sure that the login logic is executed!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297990/why-would-laravel-sessions-fail-in-just-safari-and-ie-after-switching-server). Might shed some light

Answer (score 8):

Changing the cookie name to remove the _ (underscore) worked for me.

In `app/config/session.php` changed

`'cookie' => 'laravel_session'`

to

`'cookie' => 'laravelsession'`

Comment: you saved my day !

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to Google Analytics, we removed the Analytics script in Edge and internet exploder, and now everything seems to work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone, I've recently had a very similar issue. It turns out I had two web applications on the same domain sharing the same session cookie name and while some browsers were sending the right cookie (by sheer luck I suppose), IE wasn't.

Lesson from this? Always change the default `laravel_session` cookie name :)

This post proved useful...
[How to handle multiple cookies with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056306/how-to-handle-multiple-cookies-with-the-same-name)