# Token Mismatch issue in IFrame in Internet Explorer. Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-response

### **What's the problem ?**

I am facing Token Mismatch issue when accessing the site in IFrame in Internet Explorer.

---

### **What I tried so far ?**

### **[I search for the resolution and found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297990/why-would-laravel-sessions-fail-in-just-safari-and-ie-after-switching-server)**

**Below is the code that I found in the above link**

```
App::after(function ($request,$response){
    if($request->is('external/*')){
        // IE iframe cookie fix
        $response->header('P3P', 
                  'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    }
});
```

---

### **What's the question ?**

Where should I write the above code in Laravel 5.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create [after middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#defining-middleware) and add this middleware to `web` middleware assuming you use `web` group middleware for your routes.

Sample middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class FixIeFrameMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if($request->is('external/*')){
            // IE iframe cookie fix
            $response->header('P3P', 
                      'CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

and now in `app/Http/Kernel.php` in `$middlewareGroups` property for `web` group you should add new array element:

```
 \App\Http\Middleware\FixIeFrameMiddleware::class,
```

Comment: @Helper You have the same problem as PankajGarg ?

Comment: hi unfortunately this is not woking. :)

Comment: What exactly? Is this middleware executed at all? I haven't verified the method you provided, I've just showed how to create this middleware

Comment: I have no issue if I run the site under iframe in Chrome. Issue comes when I run the site in IFrame in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but have you verified if this middleware is run at all? That was the question - how to create this middleware :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99434/discussion-between-pankaj-garg-and-marcin-nabialek).